# Can MAE be interpreted as the average standard deviation around the true value of a prediction?

Tags: regression, probability, confidence-interval, standard-deviation, accuracy

MAE is defined as the Mean Absolute Error, that is how far on average the prediction (derived from some prediction model) lies from the real value.

The standard deviation is usually interpreted as how far on average we deviate from the mean value of some distributed data.

If we assume a normal distribution, the rule of thumb is that 95% of data should fall between two standard deviations of the mean value.

I'm curious as to whether this can be applied to regression accuracy. I.e. is the true value of some prediction $y$ within the range $(y\pm(2*MAE))$ with 95% probability?

Comment: MAE is absolute difference so it is different from SD, which is squared distance. it's closer to MSE.

Comment: You're right about that! STD should be closer to RMSE, in terms of the metric. However my question should still be relevant?

Comment: For a MSE maybe. But you have to be careful about what you are talking about. Are you referring to a confidence interval or a prediction interval? A prediction interval will be wider since it has to additionally account for the uncertainty in the $\bar{y}$.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, I think I might be looking for either, I just want to determine the interval with some accuracy, and thought that it could be expressed in terms of the RMSE/MSE value